# Making all points meet in the middle using inset

Tags: modeling, mesh, workflow

I have a cylinder that I want to close the tip by making all the points meet in the very middle. Kind of like what I have here but further inward meeting to one point in the very center. When I press <kbd>I</kbd> and then <kbd>0</kbd> (which I thought would bring them all to meet in the center) nothing happens.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

You want to use the *Merge at Center* operator.  You can find it on the menu, or by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> or search for it using <kbd>Space</kbd>.  You will see more options.

Comment: Be aware that by merging all of those vertices into a single vertex you'll end up with a bunch of triangles, that might cause issues when subsurfing or using other modifiers.

Comment: In the exact case shown here, that works. But in general unless you want a single vertex merging is not the answer. For example if you want to make a blade edge, you need an EDGE in the middle of a flat face, not a single vertex. In that case the inset tool would seem to be the best, but it has no way to stop it going through itself. So how would you merge that?